# Python in a server

Tags: python, google-chrome-extension, server

I have a python script that I want to run when I get a request from a chrome extension, which wont let me run python at all. I want to know what is the easiest quickest way to set up a server to run the code when called. I have tried flask but there is very little documentation and I can get it to work properly, so that is not going to be an option.

Comment: hmm I would recommend flask, and just submitting a post request from your chrome extension (via JSON object). here is how to get a post request in flask https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20001229/how-to-get-posted-json-in-flask.

Comment: the problem with flask is I cant get my script to run, would appreciate it immensely if you could  take a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48654611/flask-program-giving-module-not-found?noredirect=1#comment84307360_48654611
or alternatively DM me to discuss the issue?