# ImportError with flask_wtf on Raspberry PI 3

Tags: python, flask, import, raspberry-pi3, flask-wtforms

first of all pls excuse my bad english skills ^^

My problem looks very simple to solve but I cant get flask_wtf running on my Raspberry Pi 3. I want to create a form with Flask-WTF but i am not able to import it.

I first installed it with

```
sudo pip install Flask-WTF
```

When I import the module

```
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
```

and run the program I get this:

```
ImportError: No module named 'flask_wtf'
```

If I try to install it again, I get:

```
Requirement already satisfied: Flask-WTF in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Not enough information. Where is the rest of your project? Are you using a virtualenv? If not, why not? Why are you installing with sudo?

Comment: Check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48781438/8928024) how to solve this. Tip: if you want to reinstall something the hard-way... remove the DL in pkgs and installed folder from site-packages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay I got a solution:
I don't know why pip installs this libary into the outdated python 2.7 directorys by default. But with pip3 it is possible to install it to python 3.

> sudo pip3 install Flask-WTF